# Rails: Speed of new record creation validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model-view-controller

Is there a way to enforce validation time in a controller? For example, if a user creates a Post, they must wait 5 seconds before creating another

I want to do this in the controller because it is a validation only for current_user obviously.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The short answer is "yes".

Comment: Another short answer. You have have timeout set at DB level, or Rails app level, and when that the DB execution takes longer than the timeout, it'll err out. I think it would make sense to do this at DB level to have 1 source of truth.

Comment: I would recommend adding a validation to the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way could be to do it in a `before_action`:

```
before_action :check_minimum_time_to_create_post, only: [:create]

def create
  ...
end

private

def check_minimum_time_to_create_post
  last_post = current_user.posts.last
  if last_post && last_post.created_at - Time.now <= 5.seconds
    redirect_to error_page
  end
end
```

But I would recommend to do it in the model like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validate :check_minimum_time_to_create_post, on: :create

  def check_minimum_time_to_create_post
    last_post = self.user.posts.last
    if last_post && last_post.created_at - Time.now <= 5.seconds
      errors[:base] << "The minimum time to create another post is xyz..."
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this gives you an idea. how it can be done.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, in the model validation I get this error:

undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Comment: is NIL because last_post.created_at is in memory but not have a created_at field yet... is NIL.